# Comparing 2 Different Excel Workbook (automated)

Tags: excel, vba, automation, compare, report

I am creating an automated comparison for 2 different workbook, which i have been doing manually for quite some time. Not sure which will be easier to do on. Currently im trying to do on VBA.

My requirements for the comparison are

- Check the sum of amount(Column D) between the 2 workbook and check if the amount match.
- if the total amount does not match, i need to compare the amount individual by Type (Column A) between the 2 workbook and should highlight the rows that does not match. Was wondering if i can automate the creation of the PivotTable or something similar like a report etc

[image: Data Sample of the 2 workbook]

[image: 2nd requirement where i need to highlight the rows that does not match between the 2 workbook. Was wondering if i can automate the creation of the PivotTable or something similar like a report etc]

Comment: You could start by recording a macro while creating a pivot table.

Comment: This sounds like a very generic thing. You could have Googled it and found a solution faster that explaining your issue and posting here.

https://bettersolutions.com/excel/workbooks/vba-comparing.htm